# Showing Bottom bar while pushing

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am hiding my tabbar while navigating to first view to secondView,But how can I show it back while poping from second view to first view

In first view

```
 -(IBAction)gotoSecondView{

   VideoDetailViewController *vdoDtlPage = [[VideoDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"VideoDetailViewController" bundle:nil];


    self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vdoDtlPage animated:YES];
    }
```

From Second View

```
  -(IBAction)back:(id)sender{

   self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=NO;
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.hidesBottom... makes the navigationController hide the bottom bar while the VC this is set for is on the stack

so instead of hiding it for the root, hide it for vdoDtlPage

```
-(IBAction)gotoSecondView{
    VideoDetailViewController *vdoDtlPage = [[VideoDetailViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"VideoDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    vdoDtlPage.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vdoDtlPage animated:YES];
}
```

then, when you pop the secondView, firstViews is the top VC again and as it has hidesBottomBar=No, the navi controller will animate in the bar again

Comment: it isn't hidden because the first VC hasn't set hides when pushed AFAIK it should appear again

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Look at the answer here [IOS: Move back two views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245603/ios-move-back-two-views/14246148#14246148)

Basically you add a notification method to your parent viewcontroller when you dismiss view `VideoDetailViewController` you call that notification and it runs a method lets say

```
  -(IBAction)back:(id)sender{

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showTabBar" object:nil];

  }
```

then your related method in your parent view contorller runs

```
- (void)showTabBar:(NSNotification *)notif
    {
        NSLog(@"Received Notification ");

        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=NO;
}
```