# Preventing `self` from creating a strong reference in blocks

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

With the recent XCode update some code blocks are displaying as warnings where ***"Block implicitly retains 'self'"***

It is my understanding that the when you create blocks it is best practice to create a weak self to keep from creating a strong reference that will not be garbage collected.

In the below example I set the `myArray` to `self->myArray` as recommended by XCode. **Does this create the strong reference?** Why can't I use 'weakSelf->myArray`? Attempting to do so results in this error:

> Dereferencing a __weak pointer is not allowed due to possible null
>   value caused by race condition, assign it to strong variable first

I thought the whole point was to create weak refrences? Isn't `weakSelf` just a pointer to `self`?

Is the `self->` even necessary in the below instance?

```
@interface SomeViewController (){
    NSMutableArray * myArray;
}
@end


- (void) doSomethingInBackground {
    // Do NSURLSessionTask on the background and onCompletion call mySuccessBlock.
}



- (SomeBlock) mySuccessBlock {

    __block __typeof__(SomeViewController) __weak * weakSelf = self;

    return ^(NSDictionary* result){

//this line is my related to my question
        self->myArray = [weakSelf sortResultsAlphabetically: result];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [weakSelf.tableView reloadData]
        });

    };
}
```

Would recasting to be the correct way?

```
SomeViewController * strongSelf = weakSelf;
strongSelf->myArray = [weakSelf sortResultsAlphabetically: result];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is right. You have to do the "weak-strong dance". You are only doing half of the dance. Pass `self` into the block as weak, but then *immediately* assign it, inside the block, to a strong reference (as in your edited "Would recasting to be the correct way?").

Comment: So inside the block I should recast to `strongSelf `and then access the array through the `strongSelf` reference?

Comment: Yes. For the full form of the "weak-strong dance", see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8248598/341994

Comment: Does the recast mater if it is in the main thread or the background thread?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I've never jumped onto the main thread just to do the assignment to a strong ref.

Comment: Perhaps you could avoid the warning by not dereferencing; use a property instead of `->`. But don't use that as an excuse not to do the full weak-strong dance. Do the dance correctly and fully.

Comment: One last question, looking at my "Would recasting to be the correct way?" example. Should the `sortResultsAlphabetically` use the weak or strong reference?

Comment: Here's the spot in my book where I give a full explanation of the weak-strong dance. http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#EXstrongWeakDance

Comment: Everything inside the block should use the strong reference. The weak reference is just to pass the reference into the block. You then _immediately_ switch to strong. That is the dance. Do it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you