# popping and pushing view controllers in same action

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

is is possible to pop a view off the navigation stack and then push another straight onto it?

I'm trying to implement a flat hierarchy for this section and would like to have a segmented controller but I can't make the segmented controller look anything liked I want, hence why I'm trying to use the navigation controller.

When a button is clicked I executed this code:

```
[[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        MapsViewController *aViewController = [[MapsViewController alloc]
                                               initWithNibName:@"MapsViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aViewController animated:NO];
[aViewController release];
```

It's popping off ok but theres no sign of any pushing! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
 MapsViewController *aViewController = [[MapsViewController alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:@"MapsViewController" bundle:nil];
     // locally store the navigation controller since
     // self.navigationController will be nil once we are popped
 UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

     // retain ourselves so that the controller will still exist once it's popped off
 [[self retain] autorelease];

     // Pop this controller and replace with another
 [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];//not to see pop

 [navController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];//to see push or u can change it to not to see.
```

Or

```
 MapsViewController *aViewController = [[MapsViewController alloc]
                                        initWithNibName:@"MapsViewController" bundle:nil];


UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;

//Get all view controllers in navigation controller currently
NSMutableArray *controllers=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:navController.viewControllers] ;

//Remove the last view controller
[controllers removeLastObject];

//set the new set of view controllers
[navController setViewControllers:controllers];

//Push a new view controller
[navController pushViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: It's not just that I can't see the push happening, it isn't happening. At least there's no evidence that it's happened.

Comment: It's an instance of MapViewController

Comment: awesome, works brilliantly. Could you please explain why you have to retain self?

Comment: otherwise it will release and move to parentViewcontroller.so eventhough u perform pushing u can't see

Comment: No working anymore for iOS 8 - the autorelease in [[self retain] autorelease]; cause a crash.

Comment: @TomerPeled Dude take a look at the OR answer. it doesn't have the autorelease.

Comment: Sorry but also the second solution doesn't work on iOS8

Comment: The following solution works good (taken from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410471/how-can-i-pop-a-view-from-a-uinavigationcontroller-and-replace-it-with-another-i/1787323?noredirect=1#comment39558837_1787323):                  IViewController *newVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
// Replace the current view controller
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self navigationController] viewControllers]];
[viewControllers removeLastObject];
[viewControllers addObject:newVC];
[[self navigationController] setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];

Comment: Upvote because of Second Solution is working for me thanks @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com For sharing this.

Answer (score 34):

In Swift:

```
let newVc = UIViewController()
var vcArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
vcArray!.removeLast()
vcArray!.append(newVc)
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(vcArray!, animated: false)
```

In case newVc exists in a Storyboard:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let newVc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewControllerIdentifier") as! UIViewController
var vcArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
vcArray!.removeLast()
vcArray!.append(newVc)
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(vcArray!, animated: false)
```

Comment: Rodrigo, salvou meu dia. vlw!

Comment: Thanks, saved my day :)

Answer (score 31):

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1619554/tomer-peled 's solution, so others can find it more easily.

This appears to be the best way to do it for iOS8:

```
UIViewController *newVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; // Replace the current view controller 
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[self navigationController] viewControllers]];
[viewControllers removeLastObject]; 
[viewControllers addObject:newVC]; 
[[self navigationController] setViewControllers:viewControllers animated:YES];
```

Comment: This solution worked for me with iOS 8 and not the selected answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 4 :**

`self.navigationController.setViewControllers[]..` doesn't worked out for me. But I am able to solve the issue by holding a navigation controller in an instance variable and do push/pop operation. Thus, silently able to change controller without glitch.

```
  guard let navigationVC = self.navigationController else { return }  
    navigationVC.popViewController(animated: false)
    navigationVC.pushViewController(myNewVC, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code to pop or push your controller.

**For objective c**

```
bool alreadyPushed = false;    
//Check if the view was already pushed
NSMutableArray *viewControllers;
if ( (viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers])) {

    for (UIViewController *aViewController in viewControllers) {

        if ([aViewController isKindOfClass:[YourControllerName class]]) {
            NSLog(@"pop your view controller");
            [self.navigationController popToViewController:aViewController animated:YES];
            alreadyPushed = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

//Push Fresh View
if( alreadyPushed == false) {

    NSLog(@"push your view controller");
    YourControllerName *YourControllerObject = [[YourControllerName alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourNibName" bundle:nil];        
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:YourControllerObject animated:YES];

}
```

**For Swift**

```
  var alreadyPushed = false            
        //Check if the view was already pushed
        if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
            for viewController in viewControllers {                    
                if let viewController = viewController as? YourControllerName {                                               
                    self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true);                        
                    print(" Push Your Controller")
                    alreadyPushed = true
                    break                        
                }
            }
        }                        
        if alreadyPushed == false {                
            let YourControllerObject = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourControllerIdentifire") as! YourControllerName             
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(YourControllerObject, animated: true)

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL Present = NO;

fifthViewController * fifthVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController"];


for (UIViewController* viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

    //This if condition checks whether the viewController's class is MyGroupViewController
    // if true that means its the MyGroupViewController (which has been pushed at some point)
    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[fifthViewController class]] )
    {

        // Here viewController is a reference of UIViewController base class of MyGroupViewController
        // but viewController holds MyGroupViewController  object so we can type cast it here
        fifthViewController *groupViewController = (fifthViewController*)viewController;
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:groupViewController animated:NO];
        Present=YES;
    }

}

if(Present==NO)
{
    [self PushAnimation];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fifthVC animated:NO];

    Present=YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3.0**

In case someone wants to go deep into the view hierarchy:

```
                //Go back to desired viewController and then push another viewController
                var viewControllers = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
                while !(viewControllers.last is MyViewControllerClass) {
                    viewControllers.removeLast()
                }
                // go to new viewController
                let anotherViewController = AnotherViewController(nibName: "AnotherViewController", bundle: nil)
                viewControllers.append(anotherViewController)
                self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by adding an extension on `UINavigationController` as follows:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    
    func popAndPushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated)
        var viewControllersCopy = viewControllers
        if viewControllersCopy.count-2 >= 0 {
            viewControllersCopy.remove(at: viewControllersCopy.count-2)
        }
        setViewControllers(viewControllersCopy, animated: false)
    }        
}
```

And use `popAndPushViewController`  in place of `pushViewController` method of `navigationController` instance on `UIViewController`.

As an example:

```
let aViewController = UIViewController() // Create instance of appropriate VC
navigationController?.popAndPushViewController(aViewController, animated: true)
```