# How/when to push a view controller immediately after popping another?

Tags: ios

I have master view controller (derived from UINavigationController) which seques to view controller A.
When the user exits A an unwind seque returns to the master controller which then seques to view controller B.

The problem I am facing is that if I have the following code in the master view controller:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToMasterViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SequeToViewControllerB" sender:self];
}
```

Then I get the error: "nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for View Controller B".

However if I remove the call to the performSeque from within the unwind seque and trigger it manually from a button on the master view controller then everything is ok. Therefore this suggests the problem is timing related, and in fact I've seen similar problems like this in the past which were related to animation timing (trying to call pushViewControllerAnimated:YES before a previous call to push has totally completed etc.).

So bearing that in mind I tried putting the seque in the code below, expecting didPopItem wouldn't get called until  view controller A had completed being popped off the stack.

```
- (void)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar didPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"HomeSeque" sender:self];
}
```

However that didn't solve it.

So how can I tell when view controller A has finished being popped off the stack so I know its safe to seque to view controller B? (Assuming that is indeed the problem, but seems like it is due to my button experiment).

Alternatively is there a way I can get the OS to transition from VC A to VC B for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the approach discussed here: [popping and pushing view controllers in same action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872852/popping-and-pushing-view-controllers-in-same-action?rq=1)

In other words, instead of using the canned unwind segue, which will call `popViewControllerAnimated:YES`, you pop by calling `popViewControllerAnimated:NO` and now you can go straight on to a push segue.

An even cleaner way is to call `setViewControllers:animated:` with the new stack of view controllers.