# UINavigationController - Pop

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am having some problems with popping items from the navigation stack and no idea why its behaving like it is.

```
Stack
A classA
B classB
C classC
D classD
```

At stack D I create another classD and add it to the stack.

```
Stack
A classA
B classB
C classC
D classD
E classD
```

Before I create E and push it on to the stack, I do a pop to get rid of D so that the stack becomes

```
Stack
A classA
B classB
C classC
E classD
```

However when I pop, the self.navigationController.viewcontrollers becomes 0 and im stuck on C with E not becoming visible. Why does the pop just remove everything and go to C?

At C in didSelectRowAtIndexPath I create a ClassD and do:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ClassD animated:YES];
```

At D in didSelectRowAtIndexPath I create another ClassD and do:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; //remove current and replace with new
[self.navigationController pushViewController:ClassD animated:YES];
```

But it doesn't seem to do what as expected. I sense the transition from pop to push seems to be too fast nothing is appearing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like the `popViewController` is also setting the `self.navigationController` to `nil`. if `self.navigationController` is `nil` then `[self.navigationController anyMethod]` does nothing.

try this (not tested):

```
UINavigationController *nav = self.navigationController;

[nav popViewControllerAnimated:NO]; //this pops myself
[nav pushViewController:anotherInstanceOfClassD animated:YES];
```

if this [causes the problem that self is beeing destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410471/how-can-i-pop-a-view-from-a-uinavigationcontroller-and-replace-it-with-another-in) then just add the following line before pop:

```
[[self retain] autorelease]
```

Comment: That seemed to work. Thanks for that and the link for more info.