# How can I remove a view from navigation controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller, navigationcontroller

I want to call a new view controller and remove the current view controller from the navigation controller stack.
For example. I am in view controller A and I call B.

Now I have in the stack A , B.
Now I want to call C (from B).
I want the stack to be A, C.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the answer.

The following code pops the current view controller.

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
// retain ourselves so that the controller will still exist once it's popped off
[[self retain] autorelease];
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

And this pushes the new one:

```
ViewControllerC *viewC = [[ViewControllerC alloc] init];
[navController pushViewController:viewC animated:TRUE];
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Any idea how to do this with ARC enabled? The compiler disallows the use of `retain`

Answer (score 22):

In the context of ARC, here's a possible solution:

```
NSMutableArray* navArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[navArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[navArray count]-1 withObject:nextViewController];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:navArray animated:YES];
```

As you can tell, this code replaces the usual push code in the view you're trying to remove from stack ("B," in your question). Line 1 copies the list of view controllers from the nav-controller stack into an `NSMutableArray`. Line 2 replaces the last (topmost) view with the view we want to go to next ("C"). Line 3 makes the actual nav-controller's stack to be our altered array, and animates the transition to the topmost item. (Of course you can't use this code in the root viewController.)

I found an alternative way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1787323/1431728) and adapted it for ARC:

```
UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
[navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[navController pushViewController:someViewController animated:YES];
```

The first line is needed because once you've popped the current view off the stack, `self.navigationController` will be `nil` and the third line won't work. Same number of lines as the previous way, but this way works through built-in methods instead of "manually" fiddling with the stack.

Comment: Thanks your second implementation was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

To remove the second-from-last navigation item:

```
NSMutableArray *navigationStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: 
    self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[navigationStack removeObjectAtIndex:[navigationStack count] - 2];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationStack;
```

For example, run this from `viewDidLoad` on controller C to remove controller B from the navigation stack.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this by first popping B from navigation stack and then pushing C into it. You should be able to use [UINavigationController popViewControllerAnimated] and [UINavigationController pushViewController:animated] for this.

Comment: This is correct but not complete. I finally fot it working but I have to retain the controller before poping it, so I can push the other view afterwards.    
    UINavigationController *navController = self.navigationController;
    [[self retain] autorelease];
    [navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Comment: According to Apple reference, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html
UINavigationController is not intended to be subclassed. Why something so simple is so complicated?

Comment: @Tony My bad, I have forgot about that. Disregard my previous comment and edit. I will remove them all...

Answer (score -2):

You can use this code.

NSMutableArray *navigationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
 [navigationArray removeAllObjects];    self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationArray;

Hope that will work for you.