# replace the top view with another view in an UINavigationController correctly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have a `UINavigationController` with the following view controllers

A -> B (B is on top)

Now for some action in B, I want to replace B with C (finally it should be A-> C).

I tried the following: when action occurs in B, I do a `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`.
In the `viewWillAppear` function of A, I check if I need to push C immediately and do so.

The problem is that when C is pushed, the transition animation is a pop-animation (slides from right to left) instead of push.
Looks like the animation applied is getting confused with the earlier pop.

How do I fix this ?

I tried passing YES in the `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];` above but that didn't solve the problem neither

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

```
NSMutableArray *vcs = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] mutableCopy];
NSUInteger lastVcIndex = [vcs count] - 1;
if (lastVcIndex > 0) {
    [vcs replaceObjectAtIndex:lastVcIndex withObject:viewControllerC];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcs animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input .. so, i need to have this code in B right ? for some reason, i dont have access to C in B and want to carry out the action in A itself ... i need to carry some pre-setup before i load and that i need to do that in A itself .. any way to carry this out in A itself ?  thanks.

Comment: Sure, you can use this code from A as well.  You need to invoke a function in A or send a message to A from B when you want it to do it.

Comment: great , i will check that and come back.

Comment: Is the conditional really needed? Since `lastVCIndex` > 0 for any view but the root, you can obviate the need for it by simply omitting this code from the root viewController. Anyway I've included another solution as well [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17328244/1431728).

Comment: @JohnK: Well, someone could always call this on the root view controller, in which case we want it to be a no-op...  It could also be a problem if someone wasn't using a navigation controller and tried to use this code.  This makes it no-op instead of crash.