# how to remove background view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I am using `UITabBarController` on a view controller i.e `launchviewcontroller` which contains code on `loadview` as below:

```
- (void)loadView
{
   viewControllers=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
    tabBarController=[[UITabBarController alloc]init];  
   MyProfileViewController *view1=[[MyProfileViewController alloc]init];
   localNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view1];
   localNavigationController.navigationBar.alpha=1.0;
   //   localNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.65 green:0.84 blue:0.88 alpha:1];
   localNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

   //    localNavigationController.navigationBar.
   [viewControllers addObject:localNavigationController];
   [view1 release];
   [localNavigationController release];
   localNavigationController=nil;


   TodaysPicksViewController *view2=[[TodaysPicksViewController alloc]initWithLeagueType:@"CFL Football"];
   localNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view2];
   localNavigationController.navigationBar.alpha=1.0;
   localNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
   [viewControllers addObject:localNavigationController];
   [view2 release];
   [localNavigationController release];
   localNavigationController=nil;


   Rules_PoliciesViewController *view3=[[Rules_PoliciesViewController alloc]init];
   localNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view3];
   localNavigationController.navigationBar.alpha=1.0;
   localNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
   [viewControllers addObject:localNavigationController];
   [view3 release];
   [localNavigationController release];
   localNavigationController=nil;

    LogoutViewController *view4=[[LogoutViewController alloc]init];
   localNavigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:view4];
   localNavigationController.navigationBar.alpha=1.0;
   localNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];
   [viewControllers addObject:localNavigationController];
   [view4 release];
   [localNavigationController release];
   localNavigationController=nil;

   appDel=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

   tabBarController.viewControllers=viewControllers;
   [appDel.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
   [viewControllers release];
```

}

Now as user goes to 4th tab to logout from app I have set a button to login again redirected to login view by adding code on button click as:

```
-(void)ClickOnLogin
{
   LoginViewController *LoginViewOb=[[LoginViewController alloc]init];
   LoginViewOb.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:LoginViewOb animated:YES];
   [LoginViewOb release];
}
```

but as login view is loaded the previous view is still at back of login view. How can I remove this view from background.

Comment: you should disable back button on login view

Comment: [How can I pop a view from a UINavigationController and replace it with another in one operation?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/410471/1041847)

Comment: in appdelegate u have load every time login page then one's user login then u can load tabbar

Comment: what is your code of Logout button?? please post that method with code..

Comment: as user licks on logout tab at the bottom he will see the label "you have successfully logout.Click here to login".code that i've implemented is in my question above.

Comment: You should use popToRootViewController on your logout button click and push the LoginViewController again, but this time with label "Click here to login".

Answer (score 0):

you should disable back button on login view

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}
```

Comment: no.i have created a viewcontroller for logout which displays label that show u have successfully logout and click on login button to login again

Comment: so can you tell that how you are able to access previous view from your login view i.e. by which means

Comment: as i m scrolling login view i can see my previous screen there which i dont want

Comment: i am not getting your words. Can u elaborate more

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33192/discussion-between-alok-and-spypriyanka)

Comment: plz suggest me some solution for this problem.any help will be truely appreciated.

Comment: i am not getting what u r trying to do it is getting me confused .  your login view would be fresh view then how u r able to scroll in that

Comment: you mean logout and login are contained in a single scroll view. If it so then u will be able to access your logout view from login view

Comment: first login screen - second screen is the one which contains tabbarcontroller- third screen login to login again

Comment: third screen login to login again ?

Comment: can u tell me in brief that after clicking logout where is the control going whether it is going to new view login view or somewhere else

Comment: and now as i see my login page again i able to see the view that contains tabbar controller at background of it which i don't wnt

Comment: login view is a kind of alert ? can u attach screen shot of login view and logout view

Comment: no.i have created a viewcontroller for logout which displays label that show u have successfully logout and click on login button to login again

Comment: it means logout and login view are same

Comment: but i have made landscape view for the same in that i will need scrollview

Comment: i am not getting on thing why you have added both screen in one single screen view

Comment: then how u can scroll b/w two views

Comment: forget above scroll view plz go thru my code again as i have posted in my question

Comment: try removing    [LoginViewOb release];

and ur code looks fine